# Fastest way to get average color of pixels section

Tags: python, winapi, win32gui, python-3.5

How can I achieve faster way to read average RGB color of a section displaying on my screen?
I have been trying to use this:

```
class DesktopWindow(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.window_id = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
        self.window_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self.window_id)

    def get_pixel_color(self, i_x, i_y):
        long_colour = win32gui.GetPixel(self.window_dc, i_x, i_y)
        i_colour = int(long_colour)
        return [i_colour & 0xff, (i_colour >> 8) & 0xff, (i_colour >> 16) & 0xff]
```

but it takse loooooot of time to read values for even 40 pixels. It is up to 700 ms depending on the colors.

Or maybe I should switch to different language, becaues it cannot be done in Python?
I want to make ambient light for my PC + TV so I need to handle changes pretty quick.

```
while 1:
    color = [0, 0, 0]
    for x in range(0, 1920, 256):
        for y in range(0, 1080, 256):
            color = list(map(add, color, dtop.get_pixel_color(x, y)))
    color = [int(color[0]/8/5), int(color[1]/8/5), int(color[2]/8/5)]
    ser.write([0xff] + color)
```

---

edit:

I have found a solution like this:

```
import win32api
import win32con
import win32gui
import win32ui

width = 5  # win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN)
height = 5  # win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN)
left = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN)
top = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN)
print(left, top)
print(width, height)
hwin = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
hwindc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwin)
srcdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwindc)

memdc = srcdc.CreateCompatibleDC()

bmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
bmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(srcdc, 1920, 1080)
memdc.SelectObject(bmp)

memdc.BitBlt((100, 100), (width, height), srcdc, (left, top), win32con.SRCCOPY)
bmpinfo = bmp.GetInfo()
bmpInt = bmp.GetBitmapBits(False)
rgb = [bmpInt[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(bmpInt), 4)]
#print(bmpInt)
for r in rgb:
    if not r == (0, 0, 0):
        print(r)
```

but I cannot measure if this is faster, because I cannot get it working with desired section. It works like a charm when i starts from point (0,0) at BitBlt, but when I change it to different value, it just returns a buch of not corresponding data to what is shown on screen.

Comment: Use `GetDIBits` to read the DC contents to a buffer in one go. `GetPixel` is incredibly inefficient.

Comment: Can you show me how can I use this with Python? I'm not that familiar with Windows API

Comment: How about openCV? Maybe this will be faster?